# Any positive real polynomial $p$ can be written as $p(x)=x|u(x)|^2+|v(x)|^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are two complex polynomials

Tags: polynomials

> Suppose $p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial such that $p(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 0$. There exists complex polynomials $u$ and $v$ such that
>   $$
> p(x)=x|u(x)|^2+|v(x)|^2.
> $$

A naive attempt is to try $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, $a\neq 0$, and see if the approach can be generalized for polynomials of higher degrees.

First of all, the assumptions for $p$ implies that $a>0$ and $c\geq 0$. If $b\geq 0$, then one can group $p$ as
$$
p(x)=x\cdot b+(ax^2+c)
$$
to find $u$ and $v$. On the other hand, if $b=-\beta<0$, then one can write
$$
p(x)=x\cdot \epsilon+(ax^2-(\beta+\epsilon)x+c)
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ is to be chosen. If $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, it is not difficult to show that
$$
g_\epsilon(x):=ax^2-(\beta+\epsilon)x+c\geq 0\quad\textrm{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$ 
One can then find correspondingly $u$ and $v$. However, it seems difficult to generalize this argument.

One could try in a different way. Suppose $p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0\geq 0$ ($a_n\neq0$) for all $x\geq 0$. Then one must have
$$
a_n>0,\quad a_0\geq 0.\tag{1}
$$ 
Suppose one has the *extra* assumption that $a_k\geq 0$ for all $k$, and write
$$
p(x)=xg(x)+h(x)\tag{2}
$$
where both $g$ and $h$ are polynomials with *even* degrees. So $g(x), h(x)\geq 0$ for *all* $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, one can use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/943369/9464). But I'm stuck for the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a result from Pólya–Szegő, I found the following proof in [VICTORIA POWERS AND BRUCE REZNICK, POLYNOMIALS THAT ARE POSITIVE ON AN INTERVAL, TRANSACTIONS OF THE
AMERICAN MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY, Volume 352, Number 10, Pages 4677–4692](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2000-352-10/S0002-9947-00-02595-2/S0002-9947-00-02595-2.pdf), Proposition 2.

Let $\Sigma \subset \Bbb R[x]$ denote the set of all polynomials which are the sum of two squares of polynomials in $\Bbb R[x]$. It is known that
$$
 (p \in \Bbb R[x], \forall x: p(x) \ge 0) \implies p \in\Sigma \, ,
$$
see for example [Prove that $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ can be represented as a sum of squares of polynomials from $\mathbb{R}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823627/prove-that-p-in-mathbbrx-can-be-represented-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-polyn). A consequence is that $\Sigma$ is closed under multiplication.

Now let $p \in  \Bbb R[x]$ be a polynomial such that $p(x) \ge 0 $ for all $x \ge 0$. It suffices to show that $p$ is contained in the set 
$$
 S = \{ f + xg \mid f, g \in \Sigma \} \subset \Bbb R[x] 
$$
because then
$$
p(x) = (a(x)^2 + b(x)^2) + x(c(x)^2 + d(x)^2) = |a(x) + ib(x)|^2 + x |c(x) + i d(x)|^2
$$
with $a, b, c, d \in \Bbb R[x]$.

First note that $S$ is closed under multiplication as well:
$$
 p_1 = f_1 + x g_1 \, , \, p_2 = f_2 + x g_2
$$
with $f_i, g_i \in \Sigma$ implies that
$$
 p_1 p_2 = (f_1f_2 + x^2g_1 g_2) + x(f_1 g_2 + f_2 g_1)
$$
with $f_1f_2 + x^2g_1 g_2 \in \Sigma$ and $f_1 g_2 + f_2 g_1 \in \Sigma$.

Therefore it suffices to write $p$ as a product of polynomials in $S$. The strictly positive roots of $p$ must occur with an even degree, and the non-real roots occur in pairs of complex conjugates. Therefore the factorisation of $p$ can be split into a product with each term being one of the following:

- $(x-\alpha)^2$ with $\alpha > 0$,
- $(x+\alpha)$  with $\alpha \ge 0$ ,
- $(x - \alpha - i \beta)(x - \alpha + i \beta)= (x-\alpha)^2 + \beta^2$.

It is easy to see that each of those factors is in $S$, and the concludes the proof.